# Hos to work with subdomains in Nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have a config file:

```
server {
    #listen       80;
    server_name  a.localhost;

    location /tiles/ {
        root www;
        allow all;
    }
}

 server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    root /www/data;

    #location / {
    #}

    location /tiles/ {
        root www;
        allow all;
    }

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   www;
        allow all;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

I use subdomain for static image content. My URL for this:

```
http://{s}.localhost/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
```

Now i want to give access to this server in local network. So i change localhost to my IP.

```
server {
    listen       192.168.80.131:80;
    server_name  a.localhost a.192.168.80.131;

    location /tiles/ {
        root www;
        allow all;
    }
}

 server {
    listen       192.168.80.131:80;
    server_name  localhost 192.168.80.131;

    root /www/data;

    #location / {
    #}

    location /tiles/ {
        root www;
        allow all;
    }

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   www;
        allow all;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
```

}

In browser i go to address `http://192.168.80.131/leaflet/index.html` and get my page. But static conntent do not appers. In console i got erros:

GET http://a.192.168.80.131/tiles/12/2737/2838.png net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

In error log i dont see any errors.
Wnat can be wrong?

Comment: `a.192.168.80.131` does not look like an IP address or a domain name. I do not understand how you expect that name to resolve.

Comment: @RichardSmith when i used `a.localhost` for subdomain its works. So i just change localhost to ip. If it is wrong decision what i gonna use for subdomain name?

Comment: You can use the `hosts` file on the machine running the browser to map a name to an IP address.

Comment: @RichardSmith i added line ` 192.168.80.131  test` to host file. but still subdomains throw same error.